# Scala Lift - LiftRules.loadResourceAsXml extract value

Tags: xml, scala, lift

I have the following:

```
LiftRules.loadResourceAsXml("/config.xml")
```

I'm trying to extract values from the following xml sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<config>

    <webroot>/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT</webroot>
    <broadcast>

        <quality>

            <primary>15</primary>
            <secondary>2</secondary>

        </quality>

    </broadcast>

</config>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

**EDIT : Added root tag**

Comment: Your example is not valid XML. A unique root tag is missing.

Comment: I've added in the root tag, do you know how to access the values?

Comment: In what form do you want those values?

Comment: Preferrably as a JValue object, e.g: {key : val, key : val}. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on extracting primary quality from that config:

```
val primaryQuality: Int = LiftRules.loadResourceAsXml("/config.xml").map { x =>
    (x \\ "quality" \ "primary" head).text.toInt
} openOr 20
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, do you know how I would map this to JValue? Like: .map(_.asJValue)

Comment: @sirjamm - try `.map(net.liftweb.json.Xml.toJson)`. Link to docs: http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.json.Xml$

Comment: Thanks alot, how would I just map the values from the broadcast element?

Comment: @sirjamm - `.map(_ \\ "broadcast").map(net.liftweb.json.Xml.toJson)`, maybe.

Comment: Perfect thanks, only issue is that the broadcast values are within a value field, is there anyway to remove this. E.g currenty we have: {value:broadcast:{quality:primary:15,secondary:2}}}, to: {broadcast:{quality:primary:15,secondary:2}}.

Comment: @sirjamm - I'm not sure, never worked with Json before, but maybe this could work - `.map(x => net.liftweb.json.Xml.toJson(x \\ "broadcast" head))`. Or you can do it by transforming returned Json value.